# Add button backend of custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I want to add a new button at the backend of a custom post type where a user can edit the post. I found the great hook called `edit_form_after_title` but it is not working. This is my code in functions.php:

```
    function update_my_data( $post ) {
    if( 'item' == $post->post_type )
            echo '<a href="#" class="button-primary">Update Data</a>';
}
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'update_my_data');
```

I tried `edit_form_top` but it is the same issue

Comment: Could it be that you're using the Gutenberg editor? Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_form_after_title/#comment-3863

Comment: Probably as this is a new wordpress installation. Is there a hook that I can use with the new wordpress version?

Comment: With the Gutenberg editor content is created in the unit of blocks instead of freeform text with inserted media, embeds and Shortcodes. So, I would suggest maybe [creating a new block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-patterns/) to fit your needs or editing (if possible) the title block. Or you can just switch to the old editor and use the `edit_form_after_title` action hook.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new Gutenberg block editor [it won't work](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_form_after_title/#comment-3863).

I tried adding a callback to the `'edit_form_after_title'` using the old WordPress editor and it works fine. I'm using WordPress version 5.2.15.

Comment: So isn't there a hook with the new Gutenberg Block editor that has the same functionality?

Comment: This [GitHub issues thread](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/1316) may be of use. One of the comments lists all the actions/filters that have been added/removed in Gutenberg. I haven't looked through all of them. But some might be of help.